# Updates to Wordpress theme template/stylesheet are not reflected when a file is edited

Tags: wordpress, caching, varnish

I am developing a theme in Wordpress. I have an issue where updates to my stylesheet (style.css) are not being reflected in the browser after FTPing a new version of the file to the server. Edits will only show up in the browser after waiting a long time, (15+ minutes). I have tried all the things mentioned [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens) **(edit: now updated to address the issue)**, which have not worked. These include:

- Making sure no caching plugins are installed in Wordpress
- Clearing the browser cache
- Trying from a different browser
- Making sure I am editing and accessing the correct file
- Checking webhost configuration panel for a caching plugin

Something seems to be caching the stylesheet but I'm not sure how this might be so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my hosting company (Certified Hosting) uses a webpage caching plugin called Varnish on their shared servers. Unfortunately there is no mention of this in the configuration panel - the only way to disable it for the domain is to submit a support ticket. Once they fixed it on the backend, my changes are now correctly being reflected without having to wait a while as before.